# Trouble with setTimeout with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, settimeout, addeventlistener, froogaloop

I have a vimeo video that I want to play 3 seconds after a button is clicked. I can get the video to play on click, but I can't seem to get the setTimeout in the right spot... any suggestions?

```
var iframe1 = document.getElementById("prelearn-1");
var player1 = $f(iframe1);

var prelearnBtn = document.getElementById("prelearn-1-btn");
prelearnBtn.addEventListener("click", setTimeout(function(){player1.api("play")}, 3000));
```

I'm using the vimeo froogaloop API.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't seem to get the setTimeout in the right spot'?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just wrap it inside a function -

```
prelearnBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        player1.api("play");
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `setTimeout` function takes in a callback *function*. Just wrap your code in an anonymous function, then it should work. Also, you might have cross-domain issues if you're attempting to access the contents of an iFrame.

```
var iframe1 = document.getElementById("prelearn-1");
var player1 = $f(iframe1);

var prelearnBtn = document.getElementById("prelearn-1-btn");
prelearnBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){setTimeout(function(){player1.api("play")}, 3000)});
```

Answer (score 1):

*ES2015* shorter syntax + utilizing the *3rd argument* of the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) will make our code shorter and nicer while keeping it readiable:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click",() => 
  setTimeout(console.log, 1000, "play")
)
```

```html
<button>Play</button>
```

The above example replaced OP's `player1.api` method with `console.log` for the sake of printing the argument, which illustrate the code works.

Answer (score 0):

AddEventlistener takes anonymous function as the second argument. So you need to wrap the `setTimeout` inside the anonymous function. Whenever the click event happens, the setTimeout code will trigger and will play the video.

```
prelearnBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        player1.api("play")
    }, 3000)
}, false);
```