# How to invoke Javascript addEventListener with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I invoked a callback `onload` and it worked but left a `TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': parameter 2 is not of type 'Object'` in the console

```
document.addEventListener('load', setTimeout(callBack, 2000));

function callBack(){
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.data);
    const tbody = document.getElementById("info");
    for (let obj in data){
        let td = document.createElement('td');
        let text = document.createTextNode(`${data[obj]}`);
        td.appendChild(text);
        tbody.appendChild(td);
    }
};
```

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755233/trouble-with-settimeout-with-addeventlistener) that prompted these changes:

```
document.addEventListener('load', function(){setTimeout(callBack, 2000)});

document.addEventListener('load', function(){setTimeout(callBack(), 2000)});
```

It doesn't display and I get no exceptions with the changes.

EDIT:
On changing the event listener line, I get no data in my HTML- so `callBack` is not being handled or called.

Comment: Um, so what is your question here?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [How to pass parameter to function using in addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024483/how-to-pass-parameter-to-function-using-in-addeventlistener)

Comment: Also why wait? .

Comment: document does not work this does: `window.addEventListener('load', () => setTimeout(callBack, 2000));`

Comment: @VLAZ actually, nothing happens. I got neither data in my HTML nor error log in the console- I'm guessing ```callBack``` wasn't invoked or called

Comment: Maybe there is nothing in localStorage.data.  Maybe your html doesn't like TDs that have no surrounding TR.

Comment: Look in the console for errors if the localStorage call fails. You need to have data in there for it to work

Comment: Why not just add `console.log("callback")` as the first line of `callBack` and see if it gets printed?

Answer (score 0):

With your sample code, you're calling a function and passing in that function's return value to the event listener.

You're supposed to pass in a function, and when the event occurs, the event listener executes that function for you.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e){
  setTimeout(callback, 2000);
});

function callback() {
  const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.data);
  const tbody = document.getElementById("info");
  for (let obj in data) {
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    let text = document.createTextNode(`${data[obj]}`);
    td.appendChild(text);
    tbody.appendChild(td);
  }
};
```

Comment: I changed it to ```window.addEventListener("load", () => {setTimeout(callBack, 2000)});``` that's because [WINDOW object and DOCUMENT object ARE NOT THE SAME!!!!!](http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/)